# MASM returns A1017:missing source filename

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, assembly, x86, masm

I'm using visual Studio 2008, but the same problem arises when I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I sure don't understand it, because when I was running Windows XP it used to work, and now I switched to Winodws 7, installing the same Visual Studio again and suddenly I get this error on the same project.

I added the `asm` file via the `add existing item` and VS2008 recognized it as an assembly file and generated the appropriate build step. When I look into the configuration options I see the following commandline being used:

```
ml.exe /c  /nologo /Fo"Debug\AddressTest.obj" /I "d:\Programme\" /W3 /Zi /errorReport:prompt  /Ta.\AddressTest.asm
```

When I was googling for this error, I found this "explanation" from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2a8yw1t.aspx) which doesn't really explain it at all.

After all, it has the extension `asm` so why would VS add the `/Ta` option in the first place? Apparently MASM is not happy with this, because in some forum I found a posting where somebody had the same problem and removed the `/Ta` from the commandline. And here is the next problem. I looked through the options but I found nowhere something that would enablke/disable the `/Ta` option. So how can I cahnge this? The only alternative that I can see for the moment is, to create custom build steps and manually put the settings there, but this is not a nice solution as I would have to maintain it myself.

**Update**

I just tried it with a custom build step and removed the `/Ta` option, but I still get that error???

Comment: Have you got spaces in the pathname for that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a stuid error, but the problem was this:

```
/I "d:\Programme\"
```

The backslash apparently confused the commandline parsing so it should be

```
/I"d:\Programme"
```

Not sure if the spaces also cause problems, but looking in the help the arguments are there without them, so I removed them as well.